# How to programmatically retrieve the name node hostname?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

The IBM Analytics Engine [docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine/getting-started.html#getting-started) have the following instructions for getting the name node hostname:

> Go to Manage Cluster in IBM® Cloud and click the nodes tab to get the name node host name. It's the host name of the management-slave1 node type.

How can I programmatically retrieve the name node host name?  Can I retrieve it via an API, or maybe I can get it by running a command over ssh.  Failing that, can I derive it from one of the host names on vcap services?

Maybe this information should be provided to users in the vcap info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this using ambari.  The solution that worked for me is captured here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844056/1033422